# update Reactive form data in angular 6

Tags: angular, forms

Unable to do update operation in my angular 6 on Reactive forms. At present i get the data and display in edit page based on customer id. but when i click the submit  operation, there is no changes in my old data. Even i didn't get any error message in console also.
This is my customer.ts code for update the form data.

```
onSubmit() {
this._customerService.updateCustomer(this.editForm.value)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.router.navigate(['list']);
    },
    error => {
      alert(error);
    });
}
```

This is the code for customer.service.ts

```
updateCustomer(customer: Customer) {
let body = {
  "name": customer.name,
  "email": customer.email,
  "primaryPhone": customer.primaryPhone,
  "alternatePhone": customer.alternatePhone,
  "address1": customer.address1,
  "address2": customer.address2,
  "address3": customer.address3,
  "city": customer.city,
  "state": customer.state,
  "country": customer.country,
  "zip": customer.zip,
};
return this.http.put(this._global.baseUrl + '/Customer/UpdateCustomer/' + customer.customerId, body, this._global.httpOptions).catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
 }
```

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz regarding this issue

Comment: I'm not sure but you put the customer in the body of the api call and then you do `data => {   this.router.navigate(['list']); }` the **data** you send back with this api call will do nothing it will just excute the route.

Comment: @murthy On which route are you currently in .?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing wildly given how little information is in the question, but did you set up the html form correctly?

For example

```
<form [formGroup]='editForm' (ngSubmit)='submit()'>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName='name' />
  </mat-form-field>

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

The button needs to be inside the `<form></form>` tags, `ngSubmit` needs to call the `submit()` function, etc.

*(there are also many other ways to correctly set up the html form, but the point is the form needs to be set up correctly)*

Comment: Sorry guys. I did a mistake in my API code not in Angular. I forget to send the Id value in API.